# Why some questions can't be linked to other questions as duplicate?

Tags: support, bug, vote-to-close

For example, I felt [What is the difference between Poorna Avatar and Ansh Avatar](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9606/3500) as duplicate of [Anshavatar and Purnavatar - are there different types of avatars?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7754/3500).

So i tried to close the question [What is the difference between Poorna Avatar and Ansh Avatar](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9606/3500). But when i tried to close it, i couldn't find the question [Anshavatar and Purnavatar - are there different types of avatars?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7754/3500) in search box of "Closing > Duplicate".

[image]

I tried with different keywords. But i couldn't find it.

What could be reason for this? How should on close such questions? Is this because linked question has no/good answers?

Comment: I'm not sure why the keyword search wasn't working (it didn't work for me either), but what always works for me is pasting the URL of the question into the box.  So I just successfully closed the question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is with using hyphen/dash (minus sign) `-` while searching.

I've found some work around for it:

- Quote your text with `"` i.e write `"Anshavatar and Purnavatar - are there different types of avatars?"`
- Or try to search without hyphen/dash (`-`) i.e write `Anshavatar and Purnavatar are there different types of avatars?`
- Or use double hyphen/dash (`--`) i.e write `Anshavatar and Purnavatar -- are there different types of avatars?`

I'm not sure about the exact technical bug but [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92426/260388) may be reversely related.

Comment: Yes. I just verified removing hyphen and it worked.